# Load data from database + ajax + php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, database

I have a question about loading multiple fields from the database and use them in javascript.

This is my table "deaths" with fields:

```
- district
- year_1999
- year_2000
- year_2001
- year_2002
- year_2003
- year_2004
- year_2005
- year_2006
- year_2007
- year_2008
- year_2009
```

Now I want to load the fields year_.... when district = 'districtname'

This is what I have: (PHP)

```
$host = "localhost";
  $user = "root";
  $pass = "root";

  $databaseName = "testdatabase";
  $tableName = "deaths";

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 1) Connect to mysql database
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

  $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
  $dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 2) Query database for data
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT year_1999,year_2000,year_2001,year_2002,year_2003,year_2004,year_2005,year_2006,year_2007,year_2008,year_2009 FROM $tableName WHERE district = 'Binnenstad'");          //query

  $data = array();
  while ( $row = mysql_fetch_row($result) )
  {
    $data[] = $row;
  }
  echo json_encode( $data );
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () 
  {
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // 2) Send a http request with AJAX http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    $.ajax({                                      
      url: './api4.php',                  //the script to call to get data          
      data: "",                        //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php
                                       //for example "id=5&parent=6"
      dataType: 'json',                //data format      
      success: function(rows)          //on recieve of reply
      {
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        // 3) Update html content
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------

        for (var i in rows)
        {
          var row = rows[i];          

          var data = row[0];

          $('#districts ul').append("<li>" + data + "</li>")
                  .append();
        } 
      } 
    });
  });
```

But this only shows the first column data (year_1999).

How can I fix this?

Comment: keeping each year in different column/table is crazy stuff

Comment: 1775531 I see in your profile that you has never accepted an answer, meanwhile that can be result of bad answers you should loss good ones in the future due your low retribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead `for (var i in rows) ...` try :

UPDATE. Looking your php closer try `something like` this to draw each year:

```
$.each(rows, function(i, data) {
    $.each(data, function(j, year) {
        $('#districts ul').append("<li>" + year + "</li>")

    });
});
```